# Where are "Your Certificates" stored in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm supposed to have some certificates installed in the "my certificates" section of Firefox, but there are none there. if I could figure out where there are stored (somewhere inside my profile directory maybe?) then I could try and restore from a backup.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1379589/remove-all-certificate-authorities-from-a-firefox-profile So I did a quick search and it seems well its not possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would be a better question for http://superuser.com, but look in your Firefox profile directory.  Certificates are stored in the `cert8.db` file. Their corresponding keys are stored in `key3.db`.

If you need additional assistance finding your Firefox profile directory, detailed instructions are available at http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles#How_to_find_your_profile.

Comment: But I am looking for the certificates as files. I want to take one and import it elsewhere.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - please start a new question for this.  However, see the "Backup..." button in the screenshot in the original question above?

Comment: No, I don't see any screen photo.

Comment: But I have managed to export and import my certificate, using Firefox' buttons. This feature is quite hidden in Firefox, and it is wrongly called "View certificates...", instead of "Manage certificates..."

Comment: cert8.db is created together with profile when I run firefox first time. What source it use at first time? Is it possbile to change mozilla certificates globally on my computer?

Comment: The db files are respectively cert9.db and key4.db on Firefox 90.0.1

Answer (score 0):

if your are on windows go to the start menu click on run and type %appdata% and go to folder Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\umqigyll.default the certificate are stored in the file cert8.db

[go here for more](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/Deleting+Cert8.db+for+Firefox)