# Is it possible to list installed certificates on Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to get/list all certificates installed on Mozilla Firefox. I would like to know if is possible to manager it with Selenium webdriver.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8458694/4056678) and the file where the certificates are stored in:

```
%appdata%/Mozilla/Firefox/<user.profile>/cert8.db
```

But I can't parse this file format. So, is possible to get all certificates installed on Firefox using Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Mozilla's certutil tool to read the database. Beware that if you run `certutil` in the command prompt you will be running a Windows certutil, not Mozilla's.

To run Mozilla's certutil you will need to download Network Security Services (NSS) from their repository, here:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/security/nss/releases/

But NSS package requires NSPR dll's to run properly. Not sure why from NSPR v4.6.2 ahead all packages are only source packages, without the required dll's, so go straight to the v4.6.1 link and download the missing dll's zipped.

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/nspr/releases/v4.6.1/

Once you put `certutil.exe` and dll's together in the same folder run the following command:

```
certutil.exe -L -d %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile_folder_name_here>
```

Where:

- -L: lists all certificates
- -d: Specify the database directory containing the certificate and key database files

For additional certutil commands see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_certutil

A Python script example is like this:

```
import subprocess
import os

ff_prof_path = '{}\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\'.format(os.environ['APPDATA'])
ff_prof_path = '{}{}'.format(ff_prof_path, os.listdir(ff_prof_path)[0])
result = subprocess.run('certutil -L -d {}'.format(ff_prof_path), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Mozilla link seems dead. Anybody has a corrected link?

Comment: @kebs see if this helps https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/certutil